# How can I verify if the checkbox is checked or not in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qt5

The following code is supposed to set the text of `nameLine` form to `this box is unchecked` when the `QCheckBox` instance `checkbox` has state `Unchecked`.

Here is the my checkbox instance declaration:

```
QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox("paid with cash!", this);
checkbox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
```

and here is the logic so far:

```
if(checkbox->checkState(Qt::Unchecked))
{
    nameLine->setText("the box is unchecked");
}
```

This code does not compile. The resulting error is the following:

```
C:\Qt\5.1.1\mingw48_32\examples\widgets\tutorials\addressbook\part1\voruskra.cpp:144: error: no matching function for call to 'QCheckBox::checkState(Qt::CheckState)'
    if(checkbox->checkState(Qt::Unchecked))
                                         ^
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So basically, this is a program that lies about the checkbox?

Answer (score 13):

Unless you are using a tristate checkbox, you can simply `if (checkbox->isChecked())`

This property is inherited way back in `QAbstractButton`. If it is a tristate checkbox, you will have to use `checkState()` as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think `checkState` doesn't take any argument. Try `if(checkbox->checkState() == Qt::Unchecked)`

Comment: yea i figured right after my comment, but then it always goes in the in the if statement, both if the checkbox is checked or not :(

Comment: Then some other thing is wrong, because this is the correct answer.

Comment: Often `isChecked()` is enough however this here is the full answer since a checkbox actually has 3 states - unchecked, partially checked and checked. A good example for partially checked is often seen in tree views where only a portion of nodes in a subtree are checked leading to a partially checked state for the subtree itself.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try like this?

```
QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox("paid with cash!", this);
checkbox->setChecked(false);
```

then for if command..

```
if(!checkbox->isChecked)
{
     nameLine->setText("the box is unchecked");
}
```